# division of two variables is returning zero , in magento2 WHY?

Tags: magento2, email

i have function which should return price of single product on email recipt:

File location :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\items\order\default.phtml

Code :

```
<td class="item-price">
      echo  $block->getItemPrice($_item);
</td>
```

but it is returning subtotal price , so in order to correct it i assign to variable and divide it with quantity like this :

```
 $zx1 = $block->getItemPrice($_item);
 $zx2 = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
 $zx = $zx1 / $zx2;
 echo $zx; ?>
```

let's assume :

> zx1 returns = Rs.50 
>   and zx2 returns = 2 on email

than why zx returns 0 ?

i tried substring and int casting function but none of them works. please help

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what values `substr() ` and type casting gives you?

Comment: var_dump(zx1) is returning this=>>>> string(53) " Rs. 140.00 "

Comment: echo substr($zx1,4); is returning  -> Rs. 110.00

Comment: it means my substring function is not working here , what can i do now alternatively

Comment: Try to change `$zx1 = $block->getItemPrice($_item);` to `$zx1 = $_item->getRowTotal()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$zx1 = $_item->getRowTotal();
$zx2 = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
$zx = $zx1 / $zx2;
echo "Rs.". $zx; ?>
```

that worked for me thank you so much Guys <3 Peace

> Special Thanks :  **George M**

Comment: If you have a multi-currency website I also suggest you to change `echo "Rs." . $zx";` to `echo $block->getOrder()->formatPrice($zx);`.

Comment: no my store deal with in only pakistan , but i note down your point  , thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you say.... `$zx1` returns Rs.50 which is not a number. When you divide a string with a number, PHP converts the string to a number. In this case it converts it to 0 because the first character is not numerical. So you get 0/2 which is 0.

Comment: yes i know that , that's why i tried substr() function but that also didn't work for me , is it a magento bug?

Comment: this is seriously freaking me out :(