# New order email template - price decimal place

Tags: magento2, orders, price, template, order-email

we have amended our Magento 2.1 to use and store prices with 4 decimal places. But then used some JS to trim/round-up on the frontend to 2 decimal places.

However, on the email templates, the price is displaying with 4 decimal places e.g. £15.99000

Can I override the default email template to format the number to 2 decimal places (since the email doesn't allow JS)

I am currently looking at

**vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml**

And the price is currently being called like this...

`<td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item); ?>
 </td>`

I tried changing the above to this instead...

`<?php echo number_format($_item->getItemPrice(), 2); ?>`

But that just seems to zero out the price, however it does read with 2 decimal places. So instead of it being £15.99 I just get £0.00

Where is my replacement code going wrong or am I even in the right place?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you can include what you changed to get 4 dp working?

Comment: Not fully but basically we used this extension as a starting point to set the system to use 4DP https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal then applied some JS to trim off the extra zeros - there is a slight moment where 4DP shows on frontend when the page loads but we'll live with it

Answer (score 0):

Mine seems to work well with using this code below.

```
<td class="item-price">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item->getOrderItem()) ?>
<td/>
```

Hopefully this will fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for replying - it didn't work unfortunately - after making this change I actually could not checkout at all

Answer (score 0):

That code should works

```
<td class="item-price">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  number_format($block->getItemPrice($_item), 2, '.', ''); ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying - this seems to wipe out the item details completely on the email. So where there would be the items listed, there is nothing

Comment: UPDATE: I am seeing this in debug.log when using the above

`[2019-06-11 12:29:56] main.CRITICAL: Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /var/view_preprocessed/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml on line 1 {"is_exception":false} []`

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is getItemPrice is pulling through more than just a number

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0eb8677b0b4e35606032e856cc1ef7c80e68829f/app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php#L99

So

`<?php echo number_format(preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $_item->getItemPrice()), 2); ?>`

Potentially you will lose currency symbol though

Comment: Thanks Dominic but again that seems to remove the full items including product name etc from the email. And I see same error in debug.log 

`Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float,`

Could/should it be converted to a float before trying to call it somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have sorted it by using this instead...

Added new variable

```
$zx1 = $_item->getRowTotal();
```

Then just displayed that

```
<?php echo $zx1; ?>
```

Thanks to this question which pointed me in the right direction...

[division of two variables is returning zero , in magento2 WHY?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215638/division-of-two-variables-is-returning-zero-in-magento2-why][1])

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use

```
<?php echo number_format($_item->getItemPrice(), 2); ?>
```

The code return " £15.99" not  "15.99"

Comment: Yeah I don't think getItemPrice is a number/float so it can't convert it. Using getRowTotal works for me. It doesn't have the currency symbol but we are only single currency so I can just add one in manually.

Comment: @RichardLaws yeah, good look